# Does decoding library affects cnn's performance?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

In training, I use opencv to decode jpg files and then use them to train a cnn image classifier.

During inference, I use both nvjpeg and opencv to decode jpg files and evaluate the trained cnn model.

evaluating with opencv decoding is much better than nvjpeg.

Is this normal or I am missing something here?